# A function $f(x)$ that increases from $0$ to $1$ when $x$ increases from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Tags: functions

I am looking for a function $f(x) \in [0,1]$ when $x \in (-\infty, +\infty)$.

$f(x)$ increases **very fast** when $x$ is **small** starting from $-\infty$, and then very slow and eventually approach $1$ when $x$ is infinity.

Comment: What about the continuity and differentiability of $f(x)$? Any restrictions?

Comment: Look up sigmoid function

Answer (score 8):

$$f(x) = \dfrac1{1+e^{-x}}$$ is one possible candidate.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function $f(x) = \frac{\arctan(x)}{\pi} + \frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

The function $$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+a^{-x}}$$ has such a property $\forall \, a>1 , a \in \mathbb{R^+}$.

The function by Leg where $a=e$ is a special case of this type of functions.